# Is it possible to stream to the same Xbox One from two different Windows 10 machine?

Tags: xbox-one, streaming, windows-10

I don't have a second machine to test this with, but would this be possible? I am thinking I could log into Windows with different accounts and stream to the Xbox one with the said accounts.  This could be useful if one only has two xbox one controllers and want to use their Xbox 360 controllers for the third and fourty players in a local 4-player coop game.

Comment: I think you mean *to* the pc *from* an xbox. But in your example, why wouldnt you just connect both 360 controllers to the same pc?

Comment: Ah yes.. that's what I meant... I will try that.. I didn't think of doing that actually. Not sure if it's possible, but will report back.